# how to play bigvideo.js in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have followed the instructions on the bigvideo.js [site](http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/) but it will not work.

**I have been able to show the video this way:**

```
     <video id="big-video-vid_html5_api" preload="auto" 
data-setup="{}" webkit-playsinline="" autoplay=""
 src="assets/vids/dock.mp4" loop></video>
```

**that works even when I remove the default script:**

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var BV = new $.BigVideo();
        BV.init();
        BV.show('http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4');
    });
</script>
```

Most online documentation gives the latter as an example on how to use bigvideo.js. It does not work for me, its supposed become the background video. How would I configure it to show on a div like these examples:

https://asana.com/

http://riskeverything.us/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first tag is just an html video tag, which is not an ideal solution to use for video as a header.

## Solution

The main issue were the dependencies, in my particular case I was missing the video.js. It is best to install with bower:

```
bower install BigVideo.js
```

this will automatically download all dependencies. Also another issue I ran into the video was sticking to the background. It was because of the bigvideo css, which used the css position:absolute.

Answer (score 1):

try passing `container` to BigVideo, as:

```
$(function() {
    BV = new $.BigVideo({container: $('#your_div_element_id')});
    BV.init();
    BV.show('http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4');
});
```

Comment: it hasnt been working, did you install with bower? or manually download all the dependencies etc?